# Caffeine async cache wih Spring Boot CacheManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, caffeine-cache

I am trying to use Spring Boot `CacheManager` with Caffeine and some `@Cacheable` annotated functions. In our tests, asynchronous calls to our controllers endpoints are having issues that seem to be related to the fact that we were using a non-asynchronous cache.

While doing some research, I have seen a lot of examples of using Caffeine manually with `CompletableFuture`, but could not found nothing with `AsyncCacheLoader` and Spring Boot `CacheManager` and `@Cacheable` annotation. It looks like `Cache` and `AsyncCache` have very distinct APIs. Is this possible to use the default Spring Boot `CacheManager` asynchronously?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Updating the answer after comment by Ben Manes.
You can use `@Cacheable` with Spring Boot Cache Manager for reactive [Spring Webflux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html) but underneath the hoods values are stored in synchronous cache.  Here is an example

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class GatewayApplication {

 @PostMapping(value ="/test", produces = "application/json")
 public Flux<String> handleRequest(@RequestBody String body) {
    return getData(body);
 }

 @Cacheable("cache")
 private Flux<String> getData(String body) {
    return WebClient.create().post()
            .uri("http://myurl")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(body))
            .retrieve().bodyToFlux(String.class).cache();
 }
}
```

As you can see in above example, its using Spring Webflux(Project reactor) and `@Cacheable` method returns Flux which is async.

You can use `AsyncCache` directly if you want reactive cache as it stores `CompleteableFutures`

Comment: I believe this stores into a synchronous cache (Spring [#26713](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26713)). Their caching support of reactive types is still an open issue (Spring [#17920](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17920)).